# Options to speed up R code when parallelization is not feasible

Tags: r, performance, simulation

I have developed a simulation, which can be quite slow (up to 6 hours), depending on values of input parameters.

Profiling my code reveals that sample() is the bottleneck, but from my knowledge, there is no better function (sample() is already optimized for maximal speed since it is written in C).

Parallelization will not work either since algorithm iterations are dependent on one another.

Any suggestions on alternatives to improve runtime?

Any advice is warmly welcomed.

Below is my simulation code:

#### Haplotype Accumulation Curve Simulator

```
HAC.sim <- function(K = 1, N, Hstar, probs, m = 0, perms = 10000, p = 0.95){

pop <- array(dim = c(c(perms, ceiling((1 - m) * N / K)), K))
haps <- as.character(1:Hstar)
specs <- 1:ceiling((1 - m) * N / K)

for (j in 1:perms){
    for (i in 1:K){
        pop[j, specs, i] <- sample(haps, size = length(specs), replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
    }
}


HAC.mat <- array(dim = c(c(perms, length(specs), K)))

for (k in specs){
    for (j in 1:perms){
        for (i in 1:K){
            ind.index <- sample(specs, size = k, replace = FALSE) 
            hap.plot <- pop[sample(1:nrow(pop), size = 1, replace = TRUE), ind.index, sample(i, size = 1, replace = TRUE)] 
            HAC.mat[j, k, i] <- length(unique(hap.plot))
        }
    }
}

means <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, mean)
lower <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.025))
upper <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.975))

d <- assign("d", data.frame(specs, means), envir = .GlobalEnv)

P <- max(means)
Q <- Hstar - max(means)
R <- assign("R", max(means) / Hstar, envir = .GlobalEnv)
S <- (Hstar - max(means)) / Hstar
Nstar <- assign("Nstar", (N * Hstar) / max(means), envir = .GlobalEnv)
X <- ((N * Hstar) / max(means)) - N

cat("\n Measures of Sampling Closeness \n \n Mean number of haplotypes sampled: " , P, "\n Mean number of haplotypes not sampled: " , Q, "\n Proportion of haplotypes sampled: " , R, "\n Proportion of haplotypes not sampled:  " , S, "\n \n Calculated mean value of N*: ", Nstar, "\n Mean number of individuals not sampled: ", X, "\n \n")

if (R < p){
    cat("Desired level of H* has not yet been reached \n")
    } else{
        cat("Desired level of H* has been reached")
}

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

plot(specs, means, type = "n", xlab = "Specimens sampled", ylab = "Unique haplotypes",  ylim = c(1, Hstar))
polygon(x = c(specs, rev(specs)), y = c(lower, rev(upper)), col = "gray")
lines(specs, means, lwd = 2)
HAC.bar <- barplot(length(specs) * probs, xlab = "Unique haplotypes", ylab = "Specimens sampled", names.arg = 1:Hstar)

}
```

#### A quick reproducible example

```
N <- 50
Hstar <- 5
probs <- rep(1/Hstar, Hstar)

HAC.sim(N = N, Hstar = Hstar, probs = probs)
```

Comment: You don't give much to go on here. However, `sample` is not written in C; there's no compiled code called in that function. `sample` calls `sample.int`, which *does* call out to external compiled code. Arranging for a suitable call to `sample.int` or even calling the external compiled code directly by replicating the `.Internal()` call used by `sample.int` may well give considerable savings as you are closer to the external code. If you are repeatedly calling `sample()`, perhaps refactor the code to call `sample` once? Again, hard to comment with so little detail/no reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks Gavin! I'll try that option and compare runtimes. BTW the simulation I vaguely refer to here is the one I am applying GAMs/SCAMs/Kriging to from CV...

Comment: I realise my comment about might be somewhat pedantic, but what I was getting at is that if you have a specific incantation calling `sample()`, and you call that incantation many times (large `N`) then you are incurring all the R-code overhead inherent to `sample()` and a bit more in `sample.int()` *before* you hit the C code that's doing the heavy lifting. Running all that R code many, many times is wasteful. So, as long as this is **not** in a package, just figure out the correct `.Internal()` call (by debugging `sample()` and `sample.int()` for your needs, and call it directly.

Comment: If you are sampling, it sounds like you're not doing the standard posterior simulation for GAMs that I've discussed with you on [stats.se] and written about in my blog posts. As such, and without it I doubt you'll get more specific help here, you need to isolate the issue to a minimal reproducible example. It doesn't matter if you exclude all the GAM simulation stuff, just have something we can run, but into which you will insert the simulation code. This is important; can you call `sample()` once and then subset that during simulation rather than repeatedly call `sample()`?

Comment: Thanks again! No, this isn't a package... I have created my own user defined function to run the simulation. Once I get the results, then I will apply the semiparametric fitting. Eventually though, combining all of it into a package seems like the logical step.

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: @F.Prive Yes, I can provide my simulation code, I will add it now.

Comment: @F.Privé Thanks. Yes, I see that now. Not sure why I didn't let you know about my old venture into Rcpp. I first wanted to clean up my code - which I did. I will now try out Rcpp on my cleaned script, but have since (today) been steered toward byte compilation using the compiler package.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, `Rcpp` is an option but would require you to rewrite parts of your code in C++. One non-invasive option is to use the `compiler` package that can offer some speed improvements with minimal effort:

```
#old R version of lapply
slow_func <- function(X, FUN, ...) {
   FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
   if (!is.list(X))
    X <- as.list(X)
   rval <- vector("list", length(X))
   for(i in seq(along = X))
    rval[i] <- list(FUN(X[[i]], ...))
   names(rval) <- names(X)          # keep `names' !
   return(rval)
}

# Compiled versions
require(compiler)
slow_func_compiled <- cmpfun(slow_func)
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.r-statistics.com/2012/04/speed-up-your-r-code-using-a-just-in-time-jit-compiler/amp/). However, if the only issue is `sample` it looks like `Rcpp` has an [alternative implemention](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-the-Rcpp-based-sample-implementation/). It looks like it is not faster in all cases though.

Comment: Thanks perhaps I will give cmpfun() a try!